# Can Outlook Calendar retrieve contacts' birth dates from People app to remind me of their birth dates?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, contacts, calendars, people

I want Outlook Calendar app to collect birth dates from People app for my contacts to remind me of their birthdays. I find it very tedious task to do it manually to create to  a new birthday calendar for my contacts' birth dates and enter it one by one.

This feature is available on my Android device and the process is done automatically as soon as I enter the birth date for a given contact. Is it available or missing and I have to request it through feedback app as usual.

- Phone: Lumia 640 XL
- OS: Windows 10 Mobile

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware this feature is available right now - though you could do this by syncing from Facebook if you had it.

You can always request a new feature through the feedback app

Comment: Thanks but the majority of my contacts don't use Facebook.

Comment: I would suggest it in the feedback app then. @mms911